# Slippry.js Slider not Scaling Images correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Using slippry.js slider on responsive site. Image original size is 600x600px.  When resized height below 400px white space shows inside the slider below the image.

Attempted replacing slider image with background-image and making background-size to cover, but made image to large when re-scaled to mobile.  Attempted changing .sy-filler class's height.  Attempted deactivating adaptiveHeight in slippry.js.

Viewing image info in Firefox shows Meta tag named viewport with content of width=device-width; height=device-width.

Couldn't find place to contact slippry.js developers, so thought someone on stack overflow might have an idea.  Below is the structure for the slider:

```
    <div class="main-slider">
    <div class="sy-box">
    <div class="sy-slides-wrap">
    <div class="sy-slides-crop">
    <ul class="slippry sy-list" style="left: -100%; transition-duration: 800ms;">
    <li class="sy-slide horizontal useCSS" style="left: 0px;">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="slide-title">
    </div>
    <img class="visible-md visible-lg" src="img/slides/home-top-slide1.jpg">
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="img/slides/home-top-slide1-m.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="sy-slide horizontal useCSS sy-active" style="left: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="slide-title">
    </div>
    <img class="visible-md visible-lg" src="img/slides/home-top-slide2.jpg">
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="img/slides/home-top-slide2-m.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="sy-slide horizontal useCSS" style="left: 200%;">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="slide-title">
    </div>
    <img class="visible-md visible-lg" src="img/slides/home-top-slide3.jpg">
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="img/slides/home-top-slide3-m.jpg">
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="sy-controls">
    <li class="sy-prev">
    <a href="#prev">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sy-next">
    <a href="#next">Next</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sy-caption-wrap">
    <div class="sy-caption" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sy-filler ready" style="padding-top: 101.781%;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="sy-pager">
    <li class="">
    <a href="#1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sy-active">
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#3">3</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .main-slider {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-box {
        min-height: 400px;
    }

    .sy-slides-wrap {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-slides-crop {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-slides-crop {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-slides-crop {
        min-height: 400px;
    }

    .sy-list {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }


    .sy-controls, .sy-controls li, .sy-list, .sy-slide, .sy-slides-crop {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .sy-controls, .sy-list, .sy-pager {
        list-style: outside none none;
    }

    .slippry li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .sy-slide {
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .slide-title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .sy-controls, .sy-slide > a, .sy-slide > a > img, .sy-slide > img {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-slide > a > img, .sy-slide > img {
        border: 0 none;
        display: block;
    }

    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }

    .sy-controls {
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .sy-controls li.sy-prev {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .sy-controls li {
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 4.2em;
        width: 10%;
        z-index: 33;
    }

    .sy-controls li.sy-next {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .sy-caption-wrap {
        bottom: 2em;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 12;
    }

    .sy-filler.ready {
        transition: padding 0.6s ease 0s;
    }

    .sy-filler {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sy-pager {
      display: none !important;
      margin: 1em 0 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .sy-pager {
      display: block;
      margin: 1em 0 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Slippry JS Settings: http://www.slippry.com/settings/